# Accessing models from another many-to-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a function that sends out group emails but I need to access the list of contacts from a particular group. I have tried EagerLoading and chaining but can't seem to get it working. So in the `sendCommunications()` function, this line is causing me issues:

`$contacts = $message->group->contact()->select(array('email_address'));`

The error message I receive from the command line is:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::contact()`

And this is what I have so far:

**CONTROLLER FUNCTIONS:**

```
public static function sendCommunications()
{
    $queued_messages = QueuedMessage::with(array('message' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('distribution_date_time', '<=', DB::raw('NOW()'));    
    }))->get();

    foreach ($queued_messages as $queued)
    {
        $message = $queued->message;
        $contacts = $message->group->contact()->select(array('email_address'));

        foreach ($contacts as $contact)
        {
            Message::send($message->email_title.'\n'.$message->email_body, $contact->email_address, $message->department->short_name);
        }
        $queued->delete();
    }
}
```

**MODELS:**

**QueuedMessage:**

```
class QueuedMessage extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'queued_message_pk';
    protected $table        = 'queued_messages';
    public $timestamps      = false;

    public function message()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Communication', 'message_fk');
    }
}
```

**Communication:**

```
class Communication extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'message_pk';
    protected $table        = 'messages';
    public $timestamps      = false;        

    public function establishment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Establishment', 'establishment_fk');
    }
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'messages_groups', 'message_fk', 'group_fk');
    }
}
```

**Group:**

```
class Group extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'group_pk';
    protected $table        = 'groups';
    public $timestamps      = false;

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Department', 'department_fk');
    }
    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Contact', 'contacts_groups', 'group_fk', 'contact_fk');
    }
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Communication', 'messages_groups', 'group_fk', 'message_fk');
    }       
}
```

**Contact:**

```
class Contact extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'contact_pk';
    protected $table        = 'contacts';
    public $timestamps      = false;        

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Department', 'department_fk');
    }
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'contacts_groups', 'contact_fk', 'group_fk');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be due to `group()` returning a collection, i.e., a group of results, not a single result.

You can't make a method call on a group of items.

You would be able to instead loop through the items returned in `group` and call your `contact` on each of them in turn, ala

```
$contacts = array();
foreach($message->group as $group){
    merge_array($contacts, $group->contact()->select(array('email_address')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your Eloquent class `Communication` it uses a `belongsToMany` relationship. When you call `$message->group` this will return a `Collection` of groups.

You can try

```
$message->group->each(function($group) use($message){
   $group->contact()->get('email_address')->each(function($contact) use($message){
          Message::send($message->email_title.'\n'.$message->email_body, $contact->email_address, $message->department->short_name);
   });
});
```

Eloquent Collection provides an [each](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#_each) function to loop through the collection which takes a callback as a parameter to perform additional operation with the collection.
Hope this helps